# Bug on Form Closing Event

Tags: c#, formclosing

I have a Messagebox to confirm the exit when the user clicks on the x icon and it works, but i just have to click the button Yes a few times until it closes. Anyone knows why or how can i fix it?

```
private void Interfaz_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       DialogResult salir = MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro que desea cerrar el programa?",    "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (salir == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Comment: Is this you first form? (I mean the one started by the Application.Run?

Comment: No, it isn't, in fact it's the last one, maybe that code closes every Form one by one and that's why i have to press the button several times. But if that's true, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test for no. You are already closing the form, there is no need to call Application.Exit and it will trigger a second call to FormClosing

```
private void Interfaz_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult salir = MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro que desea cerrar el programa?",    "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (salir == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However, I suggest to add a test for the ClosingReason.

```
private void Interfaz_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   If(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
   {
       DialogResult salir = MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro que desea cerrar el programa?",
                            "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                            MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (salir == DialogResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
 }
```